# Segmentation fault while implementing chaining in hash table after collisions occur

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement chaining (collision resolution technique in hash table). My program works fine for most of the test cases.

Here is my program (it's quite big, but I know where it is failing. So you can skip this part if you want.):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct LinkedListNode
{
    int data;
    struct LinkedListNode *next;
};

struct LinkedListNode* getNewNode()
{
    // I don't need to cast the malloc in c
    return malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedListNode));
}

struct LinkedListNode* insertAtBeginning(struct LinkedListNode** hashTable, int index, int data)
{
    struct LinkedListNode* newNode = getNewNode(); // the new node
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL; // for now I can put the next to be null

    // check if the block is containing null or not
    if (hashTable[index] == NULL)
    {
        // now just insert the new element at beginning
        hashTable[index] = newNode;
        return hashTable[index]; // returning the new address of the block
    }

    // if collisions occur
    struct LinkedListNode* blockListAddress = hashTable[index]; // the address pointing to first node of linked list
    newNode->next = blockListAddress; // storing the address of block in the next of the new linkedlist
    hashTable[index] = newNode; // changing the block address to the address of new node (as we have to insert in beginning)
    return hashTable[index];
}

struct LinkedListNode* searchMe(struct LinkedListNode** hashTable, int index, int key)
{
    struct LinkedListNode* res = NULL;
    struct LinkedListNode* temp = hashTable[index];

    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // if we just have one element in the block then the while loop below won't get executed
    // because here condition is temp->next which will be null, thus here I have written if condition
    if (hashTable[index] != NULL && hashTable[index]->data == key)
    {
        return hashTable[index];
    }

    // if not null then traverse through linked list
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nTEMP = %d", temp);
        if (key == temp->data)
            res = temp;
        printf("\ntemp->data=%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return res;
}

int hashFunction(int num)
{
    return num%10;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nEnter elements to be stored\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // declaring the hashTable of size n (i.e. size of input elements), its gonna have pointers to LinkedListNode
    struct LinkedListNode** hashTable = malloc(n*sizeof(struct LinkedListNode*)); // I have given memory to the table, now I even need to give memory to the elements in the table
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        hashTable[i] = NULL;
    }

    int d;
    printf("\nEnter the elements in array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &d);
        int hashedValue = hashFunction(d);
        hashTable[hashedValue] = insertAtBeginning(hashTable, hashedValue, d);
    }

    int key;
    printf("\nEnter the element you want to search for\n");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    int ind = hashFunction(key);
    struct LinkedListNode* res = searchMe(hashTable, ind, key);

    if (res == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNot found\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d is found\n", res->data);
    }
}


// time complexity in worst case for searching = O(n),
// average case t.c = O(1+alpha), where alpha = n/m
// n <- number of elements in hashtable
// m <- size of hashtable
// so alpha is 1 in this case
// thus average t.c = theta(1)
```

The program gives `SIGSEGV` for this test case:

> Enter elements to be stored
>
> 5
>
> Enter the elements in array
>
> 21 32 565 784 445
>
> Enter the element you want to search for
>
> 565
>
> TEMP = 35383520
>
> temp->data=445
>
> TEMP = 35383456
>
> temp->data=565
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

After debugging I found that it's throwing seg fault at line number 56, i.e.:

```
if (key == temp->data)
```

This line is written in this code snippet:

```
while (temp != NULL)
{
    printf("\nTEMP = %d", temp);
    if (key == temp->data)
        res = temp;
    printf("\ntemp->data=%d\n", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

As you can see in the failing test above that, the while loop is executing 3 times (it was supposed to be executed only twice, because the temp should point to null for the third time). And while it is executing 3rd time, it's throwing segfault at the line `if (key == temp->data)`.

It means that temp is not `NULL`, and it even doesn't has `data` field. So there might be the problem in the insertion (i.e. while inserting the next field of the newNode might not be made `NULL`, but I am properly taking care of that thing.) If there would be the problem in insertion then my code should fail of other test cases too. But the code is just failing for the specified test case above.

For example, the code passes this test case:

> [aupadhyay@localhost c]$ ./a.out
>
> Enter elements to be stored
>
> 7
>
> Enter the elements in array
>
> 21 32 565 784 445 655 84
>
> Enter the element you want to search for
>
> 565
>
> TEMP = 8063248
>
> temp->data=655
>
> TEMP = 8063216
>
> temp->data=445
>
> TEMP = 8063152
>
> temp->data=565
>
> 565 is found

I am just unable to figure it out, why does it fail the mentioned test case.

Comment: you should print out pointers using %p not %d

Comment: @ChrisTurner yes, I should (I just wanted to see the memory in decimal not in hexadecimal so I used %d), but that's ok for now, as I just used printf() for debug purpose.

Comment: `printf("\nTEMP = %d", temp);` you are trying to print a struct here with `%d`, why?

Comment: @Michi I just printed temp to see what's actually there in temp (if it would be null then it should give SIGSEGV there itself, but it's not giving SIGSEGV there, SIGSEGV is coming after accessing `data` field). Even if I remove `printf("\nTEMP = %d", temp);` problem persists

Comment: Check the [Output of Valgrind](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZW6mg3Gp).

Comment: Michi yes, I got it.  @ChrisTurner and ZeroUltimax pointed out the mistake in the main function. Memory wasn't allocated in the hashtable. Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code in many places, is that you don't ensure that when indexing into `hashTable` that you remain within the bounds that you allocate initially.

In your example, the number 565 would generate a `hashedValue` of 5. You've only allocated 5 elements in `hashTable` which covers you for the range of 0 to 4 though. Inserting into `hashTable[5]` enters the realm of undefined behaviour and your code crashes. You don't get the same problem when you enter in 7 numbers because all 7 numbers generate `hashedValue`s that are within the range 0 to 6.

Since your `hashFunction` will only return numbers between 0 and 9, you could either declare a new variable that tracks the size of `hashTable` and expands it as numbers are entered or alternatively pre-allocate it for the maximum size.

```
struct LinkedListNode** hashTable = malloc(10*sizeof(struct LinkedListNode*)); // I
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    hashTable[i] = NULL;
}
```

In the long term the other option would make more sense as it will adapt if you ever change `hashFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is here: you do not correctly initialize the hash table. You wrote:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    hashTable[i] = NULL;
}
```

Since your hashtable has 10 buckets, it should be i < 10.

When n == 5, hashTable[5] is not initialzed and has garbage. When 545 gets hashed, it gets that garbage as it's next pointer, not NULL.